# Java insert text line above specifice text in string from file with string indentation

Tags: java, string, search, replace

i have simple text im reading from file and I'm getting its content as string

```
String pomxml = "c:\\foo\\test.json";
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
```

the string content (example) is :

```
"email_settings": {
      "email.starttls.enable":"true",
      "email.port":"111",
      "email.host":"xxxx",
      "email.auth":"true",
}
```

i like to insert new string above "email.host":"xxxx", only if it finds it.
so it will look like :

```
"email_settings": {
      "email.starttls.enable":"true",
      "email.port":"111",
      "email.name":"myTest",
      "email.host":"xxxx",
      "email.auth":"true",
}
```

My question is how to insert this new line into the string

**UPDATE**
in this example it is JSON , but it can be also simple text or XML file
so i can't rely on JSON providers

Comment: OK. What is your question?

Comment: updated the question with the question

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Can you not rely on JSON provider for doing this either using Jackson or Guice using a simple if condition?

Comment: @Mohammad  you have example ?
i can't rely on json as it can be also other then json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* try doing a regex replacement here:

```
String input = "\"email_settings\": {\n      \"email.starttls.enable\":\"true\",\n      \"email.port\":\"111\",\n      \"email.host\":\"xxxx\",\n      \"email.auth\":\"true\",\n}";
String output = input.replaceAll("([ ]*\"email.host\":\".*?\")", "      \"email.name\":\"myTest\",\n$1");
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
"email_settings": {
      "email.starttls.enable":"true",
      "email.port":"111",
      "email.name":"myTest",
      "email.host":"xxxx",
      "email.auth":"true",
}
```

However, if you are dealing with proper JSON content, then you should consider using a JSON parser instead.  Parse the JSON text into a Java POJO and then write out with the new field.

Comment: Wouldn't `input.replace()` be even better here? Assuming that the target String is always the same of course.

Comment: @Amongalen Well I replace on regex pattern, not knowing how many spaces might preface the marker field above which we want to do the insert.  Yes, we could use `replace` if we assume fixed text only.

Comment: can i count how many spaces are in the [ ]* capture?

Comment: That's an open-ended question.  Can you be specific about what you want to do?

Comment: The code sample I gave is definitely working.  Most likely, you have some other problem different than the question you actually asked above.  I have answered that question already.

Comment: i went with this solution, but somethings the [  ]* doesn't capture the spaces? any idea why?

Comment: I would need to see the actual inputs which is causing the problem.  For the sample data your provided, my answer seems to work (not saying that there might not be edge cases, but I don't see any now).

Comment: i found that some times i have tabs as spaces so [ \t]* will capture tabs but how can 
i capture tabs or spaces ?

Comment: found it : ^[ \s\t|]*)

Comment: I got it.  Just add `\t` tab to the character class, that is, modify my answer and instead search for this: `"([ \t]*\"email.host\":\".*?\")"`

Answer (score 1):

```
content = content.replace("\"email.host\":", "\"email.name\":\"myTest\",\n" + "      \"email.host\":");
```

Or you could look in to libraries which parse json files.

Comment: Thanks i updated my question it can be also not json file , its just example